# I have simple slideshow in jquery, I want to automatic run

Tags: jquery, show, slide

how to use setinterval in this code? I tried different ways but it did not work

This is my html

```
<img id="picr" src="images/image1.jpg" width="400px" height="400px">
<div>
    <div id="prev">
        <input  type="button" id="testbutton" value="Prev" width="100px" height="100px">
    </div>
    <div id="next">
        <input type="button" id="testbutton" value="Next">
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is jquery,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // body...
    var pict =["images/image1.jpg", "images/image2.jpg", "images/image3.jpg"];
    var picNum=1;

    $("#prev, #next").mouseover(function(){

        $("#picr").slideUp(2000, function(){
            $("#picr").attr("src", pict[picNum]);
            picNum++;

            if (picNum>2){picNum=0;}


            $("#picr").fadeIn(2000);

        });

    });
});
```

how to use setinterval in this code? I tried different ways but it did not work

Comment: setInterval is the wrong way, imagine your interval fires again but the slideshow did not finish, just make a funtion of it that calls itself after finishing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use setInterval() fun to run automatic you must create function:

```
function playSlider() {
   $("YourButtonNextElement").click();
   t = setInterval(function () { playSlider(); }, 4000);
}
```

and in $(document).ready() call playSlider() fun

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // body...
    var pict =["images/image1.jpg", "images/image2.jpg", "images/image3.jpg"];
    var picNum=1;

    $("#prev, #next").mouseover(function(){

        $("#picr").slideUp(2000, function(){
            $("#picr").attr("src", pict[picNum]);
            picNum++;

            if (picNum>2){picNum=0;}


            $("#picr").fadeIn(2000);

        });

    });
    playSlider();
});
```